# How can I setup EC2 instance as proxy server in another country?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy

We are business that essentially provides proxy servers. our servers currently run on AWS Singapore.

But we have Malaysian clients who would like to be able to view Malaysian content from streaming services (e.g., netflix, iflix) through our servers. At the moment, they can either only view Singaporean content or nothing at all as the streaming services detect Singaporean IPs being used with Malaysian user accounts.

Does AWS have a service for us to register instance IPs as being in a different country than where the AWS server farm is?

Comment: netflix blocks all AWS IPs for streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However the aim of my question is not only limited for netflix. What I really want to know if there is some how AWS provides a way to have like a "proxy" ip that will mask the origin of the server with another location.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not have "a service for us to register instance IPs as being in a different country".

However, an AWS account can launch an Amazon EC2 instance in any region around the world and it will receive a public IP address that is (usually) mapped to that part of the world. If you use that EC2 instance, it will "appear" be be in that part of the world (because it is!).

However, please note that many online services block Amazon EC2 instance IP address ranges to prevent such practices.

Comment: Hi @john-rotenstein, thank you for your reply. 

Is there anyway that will allow me to mask the server's location with another location which other than the EC2 instance location available in AWS?

Comment: No. You would need to use another method, such as a VPN service, which makes your traffic emerge at a different location. Please note that you are trying to do something that is probably against the Terms of Service and should therefore be discouraged.